# flask flash messages not deleted from server que after get_flashed_messages

Tags: javascript, flask, flash-message

The following code keeps retrieving the same flash messages over and over, I'm using `setInterval` to call `get_flash()` once a second. The flask flash documentation says that :

> Once `get_flashed_messages` is called, the messages are deleted from the queue.

Not so here. I have queued several messages and they all get retrieved repeatedly (not a repeat of an earlier problem - I've spent hours searching).

InsertAdjacentHTML works as advertised as the messages all get appended at the end of the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_flash(){   
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                var strng = "";
                const div = document.getElementById('msg_box');
                {% for message in messages %}
                    strng = "{{message}}" + "\r";
                    div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', strng);
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("get_flash()", 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: You're doing it from Javascript not the server. That code will be evaluated once on the server side. If you look at `view source` you will be all the python was evaluated once. You need to go back to the server to get them. Not embed that code.

Comment: Are you saying I need to move my code elswhere in my template?

Comment: why isn't setInterval repeatedly calling the Javascript function get_flash causing the code to call the server again?

Comment: Because you're not calling the server again. There is no AJAX call to the server. The template is only interpreted once

Comment: OK, after watching several utube videos, and considering your remarks...I get it. A javascript function in the webpage is interpreted only on page load. Calling the function from inside the page retreives the interpreted version. Ajax causes the javascript to be interpreted (run) again.  Thx for your guidance.

Comment:  glad it helped. It not so much re-interpreting it more that the data that code works on is called from the server.